# cannot open output file debug\serbest.exe: Permission denied

Tags: c++, qt

I compile a Qt program with C++, and I got this error message:

> cannot open output file debug\serbest.exe: Permission denied
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What are these command's meaning?

How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Does this happen every time or can you build the executable some times but not others?

Comment: not every time, I just copied codes from another project. when I write all the codes it has no error. But I want to get only some part of files then there is an error occured.!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Most likely cause: serbest.exe is still running. Check with TaskManager.

Comment: I've had this one sneak up on me over and over. I've learned to just check.

Comment: I check the task manager then end the program. After I execute the codes again, I get a send report it says :
serbest.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.
And also in application output:
QMutex::lock: Deadlock detected in thread 5868

what can I do now??

Comment: Yep, exit code 1 means it is still running. This is why most programs return an exit code 0 when succesfully closing to show that there was no error.

Comment: You can also have a look at this discussion: http://tinyurl.com/2w2npff Same probleme there.

Answer (score 1):

It says the current user is not having enough right to write onto the debug folder. Check whether you can create a new file in the folder as referred to.

Comment: Yes, I was working on Windows Vista and I could put the .exe file on the desktop but not in the folder where my C code resided. I never saw my .exe file show up in the TaskManager when I was trying to compile my code.

Answer (score 0):

run your compiler software as admin. choose your compiler on start menu > right click and run as admin. you wil not probably see any permission denied errors.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this error caused because of your antivirus added this file in the limited group.
This helped me!