# Signal name: SIGSEGV error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I Keep getting this error when i try and build this app. Help?

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name: SIGSEGV

Signal meaning: Segmentation fault
```

Here is the code for the mainwindow.cpp file
It says the error is on line 122 which is the

copyAct->setEnabled(false);

this is about half way down.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit;
    setCentralWidget(textEdit);

    createActions();
    createMenus();
    createToolBars();
    createStatusBar();

    readSettings();

    connect(textEdit->document(), SIGNAL(contentsChanged()),this, SLOT(documentWasModified()));

    setCurrentFile("");
    setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if(maybeSave()){
        writeSettings();
        event->accept();
    }
    else{
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void MainWindow::newFile()
{
    if(maybeSave()){
        textEdit->clear();
        setCurrentFile("");
    }
}

void MainWindow::open()
{
    if(maybeSave()){
        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this);
        if(!fileName.isEmpty())
            loadFile(fileName);
    }
}

bool MainWindow::save()
{
    if(curFile.isEmpty()){
        return saveAs();
    }
    else{
        return saveFile(curFile);
    }
}

bool MainWindow::saveAs()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this);
    if(fileName.isEmpty())
        return false;

    return saveFile(fileName);
}

void MainWindow::about()
{
    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About Application"),
                       tr("Whatever you want it to say here!"));
}

void MainWindow::documentWasModified()
{
    setWindowModified(textEdit->document()->isModified());
}

void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
    newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
    newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
    connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));

    openAct = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
    openAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Open);
    openAct->setStatusTip(tr("Open an existing file"));
    connect(openAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));

    saveAct = new QAction(tr("&Save"), this);
    saveAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Save);
    saveAct->setStatusTip(tr("Save an open file"));
    connect(saveAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(save()));

    saveAsAct = new QAction(tr("&Save As"), this);
    saveAsAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::SaveAs);
    saveAsAct->setStatusTip(tr("Save a new file"));
    connect(openAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(saveAs()));

    exitAct = new QAction(tr("&Exit"), this);
    exitAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Close);
    exitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
    connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

    cutAct = new QAction(tr("&Cut"), this);
    cutAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Cut);
    cutAct->setStatusTip(tr("Cut the selected text"));

    pasteAct = new QAction(tr("&Paste"), this);
    pasteAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Paste);
    pasteAct->setStatusTip(tr("Paste selected text"));
    connect(pasteAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));

    aboutAct = new QAction(tr("&About"), this);
    aboutAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::UnknownKey);
    aboutAct->setStatusTip(tr("About the application"));
    connect(aboutAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(show()));

    cutAct->setEnabled(false);
    copyAct->setEnabled(false);
    connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(copyAvailable(bool)), cutAct, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
    connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(copyAvailable(bool)), copyAct, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
}

void MainWindow::createMenus()
{
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
    fileMenu->addAction(openAct);
    fileMenu->addAction(saveAct);
    fileMenu->addAction(saveAsAct);
    fileMenu->addSeparator();
    fileMenu->addAction(exitAct);

    editMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Edit"));
    editMenu->addAction(cutAct);
    editMenu->addAction(copyAct);
    editMenu->addAction(pasteAct);

    menuBar()->addSeparator();

    helpMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Help"));
    helpMenu->addAction(aboutAct);
}

void MainWindow::createToolBars()
{
    fileToolBar = addToolBar(tr("File"));
         fileToolBar->addAction(newAct);
         fileToolBar->addAction(openAct);
         fileToolBar->addAction(saveAct);

         editToolBar = addToolBar(tr("Edit"));
         editToolBar->addAction(cutAct);
         editToolBar->addAction(copyAct);
         editToolBar->addAction(pasteAct);
}

void MainWindow::createStatusBar()
{
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
}

void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Zach Starnes", "Zach's Text Editor");
    QPoint pos = settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint();
    QSize size = settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400)).toSize();
    resize(size);
    move(pos);
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Zach Starnes", "Zach's Text Editor");
    settings.setValue("pos", pos());
    settings.setValue("size", size());
}

bool MainWindow::maybeSave()
{
    if (textEdit->document()->isModified()) {
        QMessageBox::StandardButton ret;
        ret = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
                     tr("The document has been modified.\n"
                        "Do you want to save your changes?"),
                     QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);
        if (ret == QMessageBox::Save)
            return save();
        else if (ret == QMessageBox::Cancel)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
                             tr("Cannot read file %1:\n%2.")
                             .arg(fileName)
                             .arg(file.errorString()));
        return;
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
#endif
    textEdit->setPlainText(in.readAll());
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
#endif

    setCurrentFile(fileName);
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File loaded"), 2000);
}

bool MainWindow::saveFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
                             tr("Cannot write file %1:\n%2.")
                             .arg(fileName)
                             .arg(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
#endif
    out << textEdit->toPlainText();
#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
#endif

    setCurrentFile(fileName);
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File saved"), 2000);
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::setCurrentFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    curFile = fileName;
    textEdit->document()->setModified(false);
    setWindowModified(false);

    QString shownName = curFile;
    if (curFile.isEmpty())
        shownName = "untitled.txt";
    setWindowFilePath(shownName);
}

QString MainWindow::strippedName(const QString &fullFileName)
{
    return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this under a debugger or valgrind to see where the segfault occurs?

Comment: As we don't have the "yellow arrow" on our screen, you might want to point out _where_ it is. Like adding a comment in the code for us. Also, in the future you don't need to post _all_ of your program, try to keep it to the relevant code only (like the function it happens in). If more code is needed for clarification people will ask you for it.

Comment: When you try to build it, or when you try to run it?

Comment: (Assuming the process that segfaults is a test run kf your app. If it's some other part of the build you have to find out and tell us which one and how it's invoked.

Comment: In create actions you forgot to: `copyAct = new QAction(tr("Copy"), this);`, thus trying to access a object that hasn't been allocated, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like for every other action you have (which I assume are member data pointers), you've allocated some memory for:

```
aboutAct = new QAction(tr("&About"), this);
```

`copyAct` seems to be the only action you haven't allocated anything for, and therefore you are dereferencing an invalid pointer.

```
copyAct->setEnabled(false); // segfault :(
```

You are missing something like this, I assume:

```
copyAct = new QAction(tr("&Copy"), this);
```

I hope this isn't your entire `cpp` file either, as I don't see a destructor nor any `delete`'s to match all those `new` commands.

Comment: for some reason when i have debug selected it says permission denied to the output file. when i change it to release the application runs just fine.

Comment: The permission denied error will most likely be caused if the file is still open (process isn't dead etc). That's another issue though, it's hard to say what it's caused by but is definitely unrelated to your segfault.

Comment: Check to make sure a process named `yourappname.exe` is dead. Appareantly this can cause issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342654/cannot-open-output-file-debug-serbest-exe-permission-denied

Comment: Ok well if this answers your **Signal name: SIGSEGV error** question, accept it - and ask another question about qt file permissions.

Comment: wow idk what is going on. i closed out QT Creator and went back in and opened the file and it runs just fine no segfaults. any idea why this happened

Comment: Yeah, don't just stop the app and thinks it's closed. Check the task manager and make sure it's dead. If a file handle is still opened from somewhere you will NOT be able to open it.