# cannot open output file debug\SvgExample.exe: Permission denied in QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, permission-denied

When I'm run my Qt c++ programe this errors appears.I found this same problem in stackoverflow but those methods not solved my problem.to resolve this error each time I had to restart my computer.How can I solve this errors.I check `SvgExample.exe` in taskmanager but there is no such a file run.Most of the time this problem occurred,not only this project.

```
:-1: error: cannot open output file debug\SvgExample.exe: Permission denied

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here are some answers to resolve this problem and I also try those things,But not solved.

[cannot open output file debug\serbest.exe: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342654/cannot-open-output-file-debug-serbest-exe-permission-denied)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342669/7362095

Comment: The program is still running/open in the debugger when you try to compile.

Comment: @RichardCritten I check it on taskmanager,but there is no such program run. have any other way to identify programe still run or not

Comment: If you open your project in QtCreator open it as administrator. Run as admin.

Comment: @saeed how can I open it as administrator. if I run QT creator as a administrator,Is it enough? Or have any other way to run/open project as administrator?

Comment: Right click on qt creator and choose run as admin , that would be enough

Comment: If that solved your problem let me know to post as answer there are users who don't check comments.

Comment: @saeed No,Still this error occur. I run the QT as a administrator.But problem not solved.

Comment: dl [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), press ctrl+f and search for »SvgExample.exe« to find out which process is locking your exe.

Comment: @Darklighter I do so.there are no `SvgExample.exe` file run.But when I check the debug folder which not give permission to delete.After close the Qt creator still that problem happen.to delete the debug file I had to restart my computer

Comment: I’m not sure you did, Process Explorer is different from task manager, and ctrl+f there searches handles (i.a. opened files) and not running processes.

Comment: @Darklighter next time I'll take a screenshot and post here :)

Comment: It’s possible that you have to run Process Explorer as admin for something more to show up, but since your problem disappears after a reboot, it can only be a running process locking the exe, and not privileges or some such.

Comment: @Darklighter Thank ypu very much :) I'll try

Comment: @Darklighter You are correct that `SvgExample.exe` file handle by system (System process (PID=4)).but when I try to close the handle.`the handle is invalid` message displaying.How can I solve this

Comment: Do you have any Antivirus running which you could disable temporarily?

Comment: @Darklighter I'm using macafee.yes I can do it.previously I disabled it temporally.but not solved.this is really big trouble for me

Comment: i just googled around a bit, and the `Application Experience` service seems to be a thing (#2 [here](https://superuser.com/a/286518))

Comment: @Darklighter I'm using windows 10.windows 10 have't that `Application Experience` what should I do now

Comment: I don’t know. I would test in safe mode and see what happens. Currently I want to blame the anti virus.